# Combine Pandas DataFrame Rows Based on Matching Data and Boolean

Tags: pandas, data-cleaning

I have a Pandas DataFrame with sales data and columns for `year`, `ISO week`, `price`, `quantity`, and `organic [boolean]`. Because each row represents a different location, dates are repeated. I would like to combine rows with matching `year`, `ISO week`, and `organic`. Ideally, the combined row would have the average price and sum of total quantity. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: can you gives us a sample of your dataframe? `df.head()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you need is [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) from pandas. You can pass a dictionary of the different aggregations you need for each column:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'year':['2017','2018','2019','2019'], 
                   'ISO Week':[1,2,3,3],
                  'Price':[5,10,15,20],
                   'quantity':[1,2,3,4],
                  'organic':[True, False, True, True]})

   ISO Week  Price  organic  quantity  year
0         1      5     True         1  2017
1         2     10    False         2  2018
2         3     15     True         3  2019   #<------ combine
3         3     20     True         4  2019   #<------ combine

df.groupby(['year','ISO Week','organic'], as_index=False).agg({'Price':'mean', 'quantity':'sum'})

   year  ISO Week  organic  Price  quantity
0  2017         1     True    5.0         1
1  2018         2    False   10.0         2
2  2019         3     True   17.5         7
```

Comment: When adding a new data with having the same `year` as in the extant dataframe, the code doesn't work properly.
for instance when I add another year '2018' it would be:
` year  ISO Week  organic  Price  quantity`
 `0  2017         1     True      5         1`
 `1  2018         2    False     10         2`
 ` 2  2018         4     True     17         5`
  `3  2019         3    False     20         4`
  `4  2019         3     True     15         3`

Comment: @Fatemehhh, I don't quite understand what you are saying. the format in comments isn't that nice.

Comment: I'm so sorry for the format. I couldn't fix it. just add another row like '2018', 1, 20, 5, False to your dataframe. then in the result, the dataframe is not grouped by year

Comment: Right, because it's being grouped by more than just year, like the OP asked. If you want to group by just year, only use year in the groupby :)

Comment: You're totally right. thanks.